# watin after jquery button click new button not addressable

Tags: c#, jquery, watin

I have a page where a text field needs to be filled in and a search button is pressed.  I finally figured out to click the button like this:

```
ie.Eval("$('#btnSearch').click();");
```

However, after the button is successfully clicked, a new button shows up.  THIS NEW BUTTON is my problem.  It is not in the source.  In IE, using the dev tools, it won't select when I click on it. But to continue down the watin automation path I have to click on it.

If anyone can shed some light on this I'd be very grateful.  I need to click the button because it not only goes to a url but it passes a parameter based on the data entered in the original text box.

Thanks

Comment: how is the click event handler registered? what is the id of the new button

Comment: Can you post this on fiddle?